# Как определить callback в Typescript и передать значение в виде функции по умолчанию

Tags: typescript, callback

Есть метод:

```
setOverlayTimer(
  overlay: boolean,
  time = 1000,
  callback = function() {}
): ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> {
  return setTimeout(() => {
    this.setVOverlay(overlay);

    callback();
  }, time);
}
```

При комплиции получаю ошибку:

> error  Unexpected empty function  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function

Пробовал сделать `callback = () => {}` и так `callback: () => any`. Возникают другие проблемы. TS начинает требовать 3 параметра. Как указать, чтот ожидается тип `Function` и передать по умочанию функцию, чтобы не вылетала ошибка `TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`?

> **UPD** `TS 3.9.*`

Comment: На будущее. `??` работает c любыми типами данных, и с массивами тоже. нет ни малейшей причины переводить в объект. `$a['a']['b'] ?? false;` прекрасно сработает, поскольку `$var ?? default` является просто сокращенной формой оператора `isset($var) ? $var : default`. другое дело что ?? возвращает результат, то есть для проверки он не нужен. и проще написать `if(isset($a['a']['b'])` чем `if($a['a']['b'] ?? false)`. Каждый инструмент надо применять по своему назначению, а не потому что "так тоже можно"

Comment: @Ипатьев Согласен. Я запускал код, но не на многомерном...Поэтому признаю ошибку.

Comment: Да я не об этом. Я просто делюсь знаниями. переводить в объект вообще нет смысла. ?? работает с массивами. И вообще с любыми типами данных. А если уж переводить, то не надо думать что у тебя все вложенные массивы превратятся в объекты. Разумеется в объект превратится только первый уровень, а остальные вложенные элементы останутся массивами

Comment: Согласен. И  про вложенность я забыл...

Answer (score 0):

А что не так с типом `Function`?

```
function setOverlayTimer(
  overlay: boolean,
  time: number = 1000,
  callback: Function = function() {}
)
```

Ошибка `Unexpected empty function` возникает из-за отсутсвия некоторых настроек ESLint:

```json
{ "allow": ["functions"] }
{ "allow": ["arrowFunctions"] }
{ "allow": ["generatorFunctions"] }
// и т.д.
```

Подробней здесь: ESLint [no-empty-function](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-function#allow-functions)

Comment: 1. В `TS` `3.9.*` - `error  Unexpected empty function  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function`. 2. Код исполняется в броузере.

Comment: Ошибка `Unexpected empty function` возникает из-за отсутсвия некоторых настроек `ESLint`: [no-empty-function](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-function#allow-functions)

Comment: Пардон. Вы правы. Тогда да, ваш код рабочий. Не понимаю кто минусанул))

Answer (score -1):

По простому можно сделать так:

```
setOverlayTimer(
  overlay: boolean,
  time = 1000,
  callback: () => any = () => undefined
): ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

Можно явно указать тип возвращаемого занчения в `callback`:

```
setOverlayTimer(
  overlay: boolean,
  time = 1000,
  callback: () => string = () => ''
): ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

Можно указать, что `callback` не должен ничего возвращать:

```
setOverlayTimer(
  overlay: boolean,
  time = 1000,
  callback: () => void = () => undefined
): ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```